# Transmission oil quantity

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil

I wish to change the transmission oil of my two wheeler.                      I have drained the existing oil and bought the specified grade of oil from the company authorized service station.The problem is the manufacture's recommend  using **120 ml of transmission oil** in the sump but the service station guy has asked me to pour **200 ml of oil instead** saying that 120 ml of oil is not enough for it and may cause serious engine harm . What should I do?[image]

Comment: engine or transmission harm?

Comment: I remember him saying engine harm

Comment: Is the oil used for both or is the transmission separate from the engine?

Comment: What model of Honda is this? is it shaft drive rather than chain drive?  Most honda motorcycles share the engine oil and gearbox oil, however if you have a shaft driven bike then there may be additional oil requirements for the shaft drive unit itself.

Comment: Unless this is a modern 4-Stroke MX or Enduro bike such as a Honda CRF450R then the engine oil is shared with the transmission and wet clutch.

Comment: No there is seperate engine oil  and transmission oil sump.It is **Honda Activa** 110 cc 4 stroke automatic scooter.

Comment: It's quite possible that there is a transmission breather that vents into the engine air intake, if over-filled this could fart oil into the engine and cause issues with fouled plugs, sensors and Cat (if fitted) - Hence potential engine damage from a non-shared oils.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this forum](https://www.xbhp.com/talkies/do-yourself/25033-gear-oil-change-hero-pleasure-honda-activa-honda-dio.html) where owners of the Activa (and a couple other models) discuss various stuff. This thread is all about "gear oil changes."

Just at a glance, it looks like the 120mL is the correct answer. I didn't read much more, but there probably a lot more information there too.

### BUT...

I'm not saying that you should take their posts as authority. Honestly, I always say, do whatever the manufacturer says to do. **The manufacturer is the authority!** Even certified service technicians working at an authorized shop can get things wrong, but the manufacturer will be the most consistently correct (as long as no vehicle modifications have been made).

Answer (score 0):

The only information I could find for a 110cc Activa scooter on Honda's web site was for a [Activa 4G](https://www.honda2wheelersindia.com/FAQ/BrowseByProduct/2/15).

In the [manual](https://www.honda2wheelersindia.com/assets/FAQ/MaintenanceSchedule/5f77ee3c-e9be-4737-9bf7-73b54fb78cb7Owners_Manual-_Activa_4G.pdf) it states to use 0.7 liters of oil after just draining it. If the strainer is replaced, use 0.8 liters.

The manual does not say anything about transmission oil.

This information if vastly different than what you have. That means you must be careful. If you overfill the engine oil and run it that way, you could do damage. I suggest starting with the lesser amount then check the levels. Add as needed.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieRB for research but 700 ml is the engine oil quantity .Honda activa has a seperate transmission oil sump and crankcase has embosed letter saying **.12l**

Comment: Sorry if I confused things. I was only referring to what the manual I found stated. As stated, I did not find information about the transmission fluid level.

Answer (score 0):

140 mL is sufficient. Do not exceed.

Comment: Why do yo say 140 ml?

Comment: Because any higher is not good for the CVT system. 120 to 140 mL is a safe range

Comment: Use only CVT fluid from Honda, anything else will not have the same viscosity and flash point.

Comment: How did it go? Did you do anything? Or are to still thinking?

Comment: I replaced the oil , it could not take more than 120 ml of oil as it started leaking

Comment: Perfect so the estimate of 120 to 140 mL was out of the limit range. It should have been between 100 to 110 mL.